# Magento (1.9) Url rewrite to requested path

Tags: magento-1.9, php, url-rewrite

In Magento URL rewrite i create a custom redirection for login URL`'customer/account/login'` to `login.html`

But when i click the login link, its again redirect to the `'http://URLBASE/customer/account/login'` page instead of `'http://URLBASE/login.html'`.

so can you please explain how to redirect my custom URL to the request path.
[image]

Comment: how did you create the "custom redirection"?

Comment: Back-end admin page see the attached screen for your further reference.

Answer (score 3):

By the way you created the rewrite you will get this outcome.
Each time you call `login.html` in the browser you will see the login page.
But all the links in the application will still point to `customer/account/login`.

In order to make the links look like `login.html` you need to rewrite the method `Mage_Customer_Helper_Data::getLoginUrl` and make it look something like this (untested code)

```
public function getLoginUrl()
{
    $params = $this->getLoginUrlParams();
    $params['_direct' => 'login.html'];
    return $this->_getUrl('', $params);
}
```

Comment: i also create a custom URL for registration URL('customer/account/create') for this also i need to change in code ? so when ever i create a custom URL ,i need to put into the href attribute to manually ?

Answer (score 1):

### Create your custom module

And over-right the function ***getLoginUrl()*** class :: Mage_Customer_Helper_Data.

This is an helper class so you need to create the your Helper class :

[Create or Over-right](http://www.pierrefay.com/magento-helper-howto-tutorial-113) magento helper classes.

with following code:

*$params = $this->getLoginUrlParams();
$params['customer'] = 'login.html';
return $this->_getUrl('', $params);*

Comment: i also create a custom URL for registration URL('customer/account/create') for this also i need to change in code ? so when ever i create a custom URL ,i need to put into the href attribute to manually ? –  senthil 1 hour ago

Answer (score 0):

Currently looking at this screenshot I don't see the dropdown selected for redirect = Yes

or am I missing something here?